# using concat in ADF with a pipeline parameter value

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline with a copy activity from storage.

I'm using the **concat** method to combine number of parameters to create the folder path in the Storage.

I have a wildcardFolderPath field which gets its data from the parameters file.
Part of the data is string and the other is a pipeline parameter

```
 "wildcardFolderPath": {
        "value": "[concat(parameters('folderPath'), '/', parameters('folderTime')]",
        "type": "Expression"
        }
```

When the pipeline runs, the string param **folderPath** is retrieved as is but the value of **folderTime** is not evaluated and this is what I see.

**formatDateTime(pipeline().parameters.currentScheduleDateTime)** instead of the datetime string.

I also tried using:

@concat(parameters('folderPath'), '/', parameters('folderTime')

and

@{concat(parameters('folderPath'), '/', parameters('folderTime')}

but I get: The workflow parameter 'folderPath' is not found.

Anyone encountered such an issue?

Comment: All expressions in Azure Data Factory start with the @ symbol.

Comment: @wBob - I updated my post - I also tried using the @ sign but the 1st param isn't found

Comment: Try building the expression up using the Expression Builder one part at a time.  I often use a Set Variable task for debugging expression building, ie try and assign the value to a variable, get it right before you assign it to your main task.  Any parameters or variables in your pipeline are visible within the Expression Builder so double-click them to add them to your expression.

Answer (score 2):

Create a parameter at pipeline level and pass in the expression builder with the following syntax.

`@pipeline().parameters.parametername`

**Example**:

You can add the parameter inside Add dynamic content if its not created before and select the parameters created to build an expression.

`@concat(pipeline().parameters.Folderpath, '/', pipeline().parameters.Filedate)`

[image]

Code:

[image]